# Running XQuery transformation from XSLT

Tags: xslt, xquery

I have some XQuery files, which are generally crafted for syntax checking of atomic types `xs:ID` and `xs:IDREF`.

Is there any pure XSLT way (except any third party like [zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/)! or [marklogic](http://www.marklogic.com/) or without using `java` custom extension functions.

So far I've thought to write extension functions(using «xsl:function»). If anyone have any other idea? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This question was asked some 3 months ago, and it was resolved. Someone who vote down, would care to explain the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mix XSLT and XQuery then I think you need a product allowing that with the help of extension functions, like Saxon does with http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/query.xml.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reference. I think it might solve my purpose.

Comment: As well as saxon:query(), which executes a query constructed dynamically, Saxon has saxon:import-query which imports an XQuery library module statically. http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/instructions/import-query.xml